# How to reference a file locally within my class

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to use `file_get_contents` to reference a `.json` file in my module.

My directory structure is as follows

**my custom field which is trying to reference the json file**

`/models/fields.stackexchangesites.php`

**my json file**

`/media/js/sites.json`

If I use

```
    $json = 'modules/mod_kou_stack_exchange/media/js/sites.json';
    $json = file_get_contents($json);
```

PHP cannot find the file.  I think perhaps because it is trying to reference it from the original file location.  If I put the full location in the file it works, so long as I add an exception in Admin Tools.  I don't want to hard code the URL as it might be used on other sites.

So then I have the option to use the URI function in Joomla.

https://docs.joomla.org/URLs_in_Joomla

However, if I try to use

```
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;
$uri = Uri::getInstance();
$url = $uri->toString();
```

within my code, it is then not accessible within the class that I am using

```
class JFormFieldStackexchangesites extends JFormFieldList
```

If I try to add `use` `$uri` and `$url` within the class that doesn't work either.

I'm sure this must be something to do with scope but having tried a few different ways I can't understand how to get it working.

Can anyone help me to understand how to get this working?
And can anyone help me to understand why a relative path doesn't work?

Comment: Is the JSON file in `ROOT/media/...` or `ROOT/modules/mod_kou_stack_exchange/media/...`?

Comment: Actually both lol.  :)  Let's use media :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `JUri` for fetching local files. It returns the web address of your site. Fetching files over HTTP is extremely slow compared to fetching files locally. Use one of `JPATH` constants to get a local filesystem path, e.g.:

```
$json = JPATH_BASE . '/modules/mod_kou_stack_exchange/media/js/sites.json';
$json = file_get_contents($json);
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Constants

Comment: Is it just PATH_BASE under the new naming conventions / Namespacing?

Comment: No, it's a global constant. It exists since at least 1.5. There is no `PATH_BASE` constant in Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filepath:

```
JUri::base() . '/modules/mod_kou_stack_exchange/media/js/sites.json'
```

The filesystem equivalent of, eg. `/public_html/yoursite/modules/...` or `/htdocs/yoursite/modules/...` where Joomla is installed in `yoursite` directory.

Comment: But we don't need to use `JUri` any more right?  We can just use `Uri::base()`.  Now I see the problem, it is because I am in the administrator, so `Uri::base()` is in fact with /administrator on the end.  Ah ha!  I can use `Uri::root()`

Comment: Technically yes, `JURI` has been deprecated, but as no new features are being pushed to 3.X, it won't _stop working_ in Joomla 4 either, it'll likely be removed completely in Joomla 5.

Comment: Even so I'd rather do the most up-to-date way for the sake of learning best practice :)